# typesetting column vector

Tags: math-mode, macros, matrices, vector

I would like to define a command which typesets a column vector.

For one vector I can have something like:

```
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
\end{array}
\right)
```

I would like the command to produce such a vector, for either 2 or 3 arguments. `\colvec{a}{b}{c}` should produce the same vector as above only with one more entry where `\colvec{a}{b}` will produce the above vector. How should I do it? I tried to overload a command name but that's impossible.

Comment: I've added a general solution (with a different syntax) at [Typesetting a row vector](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39051/typesetting-a-row-vector)

Comment: Special case of [math mode - How to add a matrix to a LaTeX document - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28608/how-to-add-a-matrix-to-a-latex-document/28611#28611)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Note that you have extra space around your vector. You should probably using something like (`pmatrix` is part of the `amsmath` package)

```
\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}
```

The standard LaTeX `\newcommand` provides a way to have a single optional argument.

```
\newcommand*\colvec[3][]{
    \begin{pmatrix}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else#1\\\fi#2\\#3\end{pmatrix}
}
```

Note that you have to use `\colvec[a]{b}{c}` if you want three elements or `\colvec{a}{b}` if you want two.

**Update**
As per your request in the comments, here's one that takes any number of elements based on the number passed in the first argument.

```
\newcount\colveccount
\newcommand*\colvec[1]{
        \global\colveccount#1
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \colvecnext
}
\def\colvecnext#1{
        #1
        \global\advance\colveccount-1
        \ifnum\colveccount>0
                \\
                \expandafter\colvecnext
        \else
                \end{pmatrix}
        \fi
}
```

You use it exactly as you wanted, `\colvec{5}{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}`.

Comment: Can it be extended to a vector of arbitrary length? say something like: \colvec{5}{a}{b}{c}{d}{e} will produce a column vector with 5 entries?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. Seems like more hassle than it's worth though. How about `\newcommand*\colvec[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}` and you write `\colvec{a\\b\\c\\d\\e}`?

Comment: Yes!!! This is what I was looking for! Simple and easy to use. Thanks!

Comment: the `smallpmatrix` from `mathtools` may also be handy

Comment: It's `psmallmatrix` not `smallpmatrix`. Just to clear up any mistakes (run into that problem just now).

Comment: How do we get a rectangular, not parentheses, vector?

Answer (score 13):

This is a more "TeX" approach. The number of rows is arbitrary. The columns are aligned right by default, but can be c or l as well:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Spvek}[2][r]{%
  \gdef\@VORNE{1}
  \left(\hskip-\arraycolsep%
    \begin{array}{#1}\vekSp@lten{#2}\end{array}%
  \hskip-\arraycolsep\right)}

\def\vekSp@lten#1{\xvekSp@lten#1;vekL@stLine;}
\def\vekL@stLine{vekL@stLine}
\def\xvekSp@lten#1;{\def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\vekL@stLine
  \else
    \ifnum\@VORNE=1\gdef\@VORNE{0}
    \else\@arraycr\fi%
    #1%
    \expandafter\xvekSp@lten
  \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
\Spvek{1;-2} \quad \Spvek[l]{1;-2;3}\quad \Spvek[c]{1;-2;-3}\quad\Spvek{1;2;-3;4}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output will be:

[image]

Comment: @percusse How did you crop the picture? I tried, but couldn't find a way. Thank you for cropping.

Comment: I did it manually using Paint :)

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld: See [How do you crop an attached PDF?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1799/5764)

Comment: +1 Just what I was looking for. But what does *Spvek* mean?

Comment: Turns out to be abb. for spaltenvektor, in german
http://www.pbreitfeld.de/schule2e.sty

Answer (score 9):

I would to supplement the solution above about \Spvek by Peter B.
Yes, it is a more "TeX" approach but pure "TeX" approach is in two lines only:

```
\def\spvec#1{\left(\vcenter{\halign{\hfil$##$\hfil\cr \spvecA#1;;}}\right)}
\def\spvecA#1;{\if;#1;\else #1\cr \expandafter \spvecA \fi}

$\spvec{1;2;3} + \spvec{1;2;-3;4} + \spvec{1;2}$
```

This solution will be work in LaTeX too because only TeX primitives are used here.

Comment: Does anyone care to elaborate on this code? I like it and want to modify it, but anything I attempt will fail. What is going on here `$##$` ?

Comment: @fborchers Late reply, but in case someone come across this to learn TeX primitive commands read the TeXbook. See also [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?rq=1) -- (for one written by wipet, see [TeX in a nutshell](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf)) Generally it takes a lot of effort to learn it however.

Answer (score 7):

For vectors with only two elements, or any doublet you want to express in column form, there is a standard LaTeX command in math mode $\binom{a}{b}$ or alternatively ${n \choose k}$. These look nice with tight vertically lengthened parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my KISS-like solution (which is just a wrapper for `pmatrix` from the `amsmath` package, inspired by [Garrys answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2712/56139)):

```
\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}
```

Usage:

```
\myvec{x\\y\\z}
```

The good thing is, you don't need to specify a number of elements or anything. You can just add more elements with `\\`. It also looks tidier in the tex-file then using the `pmatrix` environment itself.

You can also use it for row-vectors:

```
\myvec{a&b&c}
```

(For completion: Matrices work aswell, obviously: `\myvec{a&b \\ c&d}`)

Answer (score 5):

Since you specified only wanting two or three arguments (not an arbitrary number of them, as others here have given solutions for), you can use the xparse package to define commands with optional braced arguments.  Something like (untested)

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \colvec {mmg} {%
  \IfNoValueTF #3 {%
    \twocolvec {#1}{#2}
  }{%
    \threecolvec {#1}{#2}{#3}
  }%
}
```

Where the two intermediate functions (defined as appropriate) typeset the array as appropriate.

Comment: Does this means that I have to define separately the function \twocolvec and \threecolvec?

Answer (score 2):

Years later and not very tex-y, but for some reason I really wanted to use commas as separators and ended up putting together the following:

```
\usepackage{iftex}
\RequireLuaTeX
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
mycolvec = { }
function mycolvec.replace(input)
  tex.sprint(
    "\\ensuremath{\\begin{pmatrix}"
      .. string.gsub(input, ",", " \\\\ ")
      .. "\\end{pmatrix}}")
end
\end{luacode*}
\def\colvec#1{\directlua{mycolvec.replace("#1")}}
```

Which, when added to the header, allows you to write out column vectors like this:

```
\colvec{1, 2, 3}
\colvec{8,6,7,5,3,0,9}
```

This requires that you compile your tex with [lualatex](http://www.luatex.org/) instead of xetex or pdftex, but that shouldn't affect the rest of your document.

The seperator can be changed to any arbitrary character by changing the `","` on the `.. string.gsub(...` line.

EDIT:
This method breaks when entering tokens (i.e. `\colvec{1 \cdot 2, 2 \cdot 3}`), for the reasons described [here](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Writing_Lua_in_TeX#Backslash). As such I'll recommend [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39054/169846) on a related question, which provides the functionality I claim here without the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Se.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer a macro `\colvec` within whose argument you can supply an arbitrary amount of undelimited arguments whereof each one will be taken for a component of the one-column-vector:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, \UD@PassFirstToSecond,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBlank, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%.............................................................................
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}.}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  { #1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Process an arbitrary amount of undelimited arguments as 
%% a one-column-vector:
%%
%% The macro \colvec processes an undelimited argument which in
%% turn consists of an arbitrary amount of undelimited arguments.
%% Each of these undelimited arguments is taken for a row/component
%% of a one-column-vector.
%%
%% You can have spaces between undelimited arguments as (La)TeX does discard
%% spaces that precede undelimited arguments.
%%
%% You can omit braces with undelimited arguments that consist of a 
%% single token. 
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\colvec[1]{%
  \colvecloop{#1}{}%
}%
\newcommand\colvecloop[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{%
     \begin{pmatrix}#2\end{pmatrix}%
  }{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\UD@Exchange\UD@ExtractFirstArg{#1}{#2}\\}%
      {\expandafter\colvecloop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|$\colvec{{a}{b}{c}{d}}$| yields:
$\colvec{{a}{b}{c}{d}}$

\verb|$\colvec{ {a} {b} {c} {d} {e} }$| yields:
$\colvec{ {a} {b} {c} {d} {e} }$

\verb|$\colvec{ {a} {b} {c} {d} {e}fg }$| yields:
$\colvec{ {a} {b} {c} {d} {e}fg }$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This post presents another possible approach. It improves [on this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178761/154857) earlier post above. The idea is to use a similar plain TeX mechanism, but wrap it up in `amsmath`s high level `pmatrix` environment. This helps with fractions for example. The interface with parentheses is the same as used by PSTricks. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\vector(#1){%
\mathchoice%
    {\pmatrix@i{\vector@i#1,,}}%
    {\pmatrix@ii{\vector@i#1,,}}%
    {}% scriptstyle too small,
    {}% ss style too small.
}
\def\vector@i#1,{\if,#1,\else{#1}\cr\expandafter\vector@i\fi}
\def\pmatrix@i#1{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
\def\pmatrix@ii#1{\left(\!\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\!\right)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\vector(-3,+4,5)$ and $\vector(-3,+4,5)$
\end{document}
```

When typesetting vectors with lots of fractions it is advisable to increase vertical spacing with:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}% stretch value 1.1 for example
```

[image: example of the command vector in use]

Because the macros make use of the `@i` notation the code will have to be placed inside at `\makeatletter` - `\makeatother` wrapping before document begins.

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483410/154857) for a similar solution for row vectors.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: done.