# How to resize a matrix?

Tags: fontsize, matrices, scaling

I want to see How to reduce the size of a matrix ?

I have this code:

```
    \begin{center}
                \[
                \begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
                {\{1\}\{2\}\{3\}} & {\{1,2\}\{3\}} & {\{1,3\}\{2\}} & {\{1\}\{2,3\}} & {\{1,2,3\}} \\
                \begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
                  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & {\{1\}\{2\}\{3\}} \\
                  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & {\{1,2\}\{3\}} \\
                  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & {\{1,3\}\{2\}} \\
                  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & {\{1\}\{2,3\}} \\
                  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & {\{1,2,3\}} \\
                \end{block}
                \end{blockarray}


\]
    \end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could try some experimenting with smallmatrix. (You'll need amsmath package.) See e.g. [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28608/latex-how-to-add-a-matrix-in-a-latex-document).

Comment: it's a last resort, but packing the whole thing into `\scalebox` would allow you to reduce the size to "just small enough".  i'd probably try reducing the inter-column spacing a bit first.

Comment: I think the slide would be easier to read with the row labels on the left rather than the right. You might also omit the zeroes below the diagonal to make the upper triangularity clear. (This doesn't address your LaTeX question but might help your audience.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could go

```
 \small\[....
```

To reduce the size of all math or

```
  \[\scriptstyle
```

To reduce it all in a different way

Or if you want to maintain the font size you need to experiment with reducing inter-column space (`\tabcolsep`)