# How to write an m⨉n matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: matrices

I tried using the below code but it works only for 2⨉2 matrix.

```
 \[
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 \\
   3 & 4 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\]
```

Now the following doesn't work for me:

```
\[
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
   3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
  \end{array} } \right]
\]
```

Comment: It should work with any size. Can you be more specific about what happens when it "doesn't work"? And give an example of input that doesn't give the output you want?

Comment: General question (instead of debugging question): [math mode - How to add a matrix to a LaTeX document - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28608/how-to-add-a-matrix-to-a-latex-document/28611#28611)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the example you have, you need the opening line to be

```
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
```

rather than

```
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
```

When you start with just two `c`s, you're telling it the matrix only has two columns (and that you want them centered). Then it breaks when you give it data for 5 columns.

Comment: @strpeter that's no reason to downvote, it's a valid answer

Answer (score 93):

A better way to do it, as the TheHe meantioned, is with the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `bmatrix` environment will give you `[]` braces. `()` braces are also very common. They are created with the `pmatrix` environment. To include a matrix inline, you can write:

```
$M = \left\[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{smallmatrix} \right\]$
```

Comment: In `mathtools` we also have `bsmallmatrix` environment.

Comment: I don't like it, it only has one line! ![matrix](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a6N8w.png)

Comment: He wrote '\' instead of '\\'. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Astrinus: Thank you. Actually this was not my mistake: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/something-messed-with-my-answers-backslashes-and-newlines. I hope this is fixed.

Answer (score 14):

if you use the `amsmath` package, you can chose out of a lot of matrices like `pmatrix` or `bmatrix`.

Check out [this list at Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays).

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 11):

Using the `pmatrix` (p for parentheses) or `bmatrix` (b for brackets) environments as suggested above, also yields much better spacing than does `array` with `\left(` and `\right)` (for parentheses) or `\left[` and `\right]` (for brackets). With `array`, the space between the parenthesis or bracket and the numbers is too large. You can see it for yourself comparing the results of this code:

```
\begin{equation}
R^2 = 
\left({\begin{array}{cc} c & s \end{array}}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} c \\ s \end{array}\right) 
= c^2 + s^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
R^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix} c & s \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} c \\ s \end{pmatrix} 
= c^2 + s^2
\end{equation}
```

That outputs the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because you have declared 2 columns (cc). Number of columns in your case should be 4, i.e., cccc. Then it will work.

Comment: Please. add MWE, that OP will be able simple test your (correct) solution.