# Can't write d equation in latex

Tags: equations

Am Trying To Typeset An EQUATION That Has 3 Braces As Per The Image BELOW
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/52VXJ.jpg)
I have managed to type it using the left and right braces[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Don't post code as an image!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `amsmath`'s `pmatrix` environment instead of `tabular`, as described in [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70035/74695) answers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & x_1 & \cdots \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
      a_1 \\
      a_2\\
      \vdots
   \end{pmatrix}
   =
   \begin{pmatrix}
     y_n \\
     f_1 \\
     \vdots
   \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation)

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: This is really helpful.. Appreciate

Comment: @kofooye if you find this answered your question, can you accept it? Thanks :-)