# matrix operations in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

How can I create matrices in general in LaTeX? As well as the one below?
[image]

Are there packages that are preferred over others?

Comment: The `amsmath` package, and its `pmatrix` and `bmatrix` environments.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28608

Answer (score 4):

Use `amsmath`: it defines 6 types of matrix environments: `matrix`  (without any delimiter), `pmatrix` (delimiters: `( )`), `bmatrix` (`[ ]`), `Bmatrix` (`{ }`), `vmatrix` (`| |`), `Vmatrix` (`|| ||`). Columns are centred.

Still better: with `mathtools`, an extension of `amsmath`, you have  starred variants which accept an optional argument for the columns alignment (`[l]`, `[r]` or `[c]`, valid for all columns).

Here is a code for your image:

```
\[ \begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
     \sin\theta & \cos\theta
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix} \]
```

The use of `\[ ... \]` can be substituted by the equation environment `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`