# How do I typeset a 2x2 matrix in an inline equation?

Tags: equations, matrices, amsart

Consider:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \subsection {\bfseries Shembulli i dyte, Matrica.} 
 Konsiderojm matricen
 \begin{equation*} 
 a = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}. 
 Per ndonje e numer te tipit integjer n do te kemi formen e pergjitheshme: 
 \end{document}
```

This equation: `{equation*} a = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}`

Comment: Related: [How to add a matrix to a LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28608/5764)

Answer (score 19):

You could use the `smallmatrix` environment for inline math use:

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
 \begin{document}
 \setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
 \subsection{Shembulli i dyte, Matrica.}
 Konsiderojm matricen 
 $a = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.
 Per ndonje e numer te tipit integjer n do te kemi formen e pergjitheshme:
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can have a simpler  way to type these matrices: use the `psmallmatrix` or `psmallmatrix*` command from `mathtools`.  The starred version accepts as an optional argument the columns alignment (`[r]`, `[l]` or the default `[c]`).

Similarly, you have the `bsmallmatrix`, `Bsmallmatrix`, `vsmallmatrix` or `Vsmallmatrix` environments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{nccmath}

 \begin{document}

 \subsection {\bfseries Shembulli i dyte, Matrica.}

 Konsiderojm matricen
 $ a = \begin{psmallmatrix}-1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix} \neq \begin{psmallmatrix*}[r]-1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix*} $.
 Per ndonje e numer te tipit integjer n do te kemi formen e pergjitheshme:
     \[ \begin{pmatrix*}[r]-1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix*} \]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Always use  $ for inline:

```
$a = (\begin{matrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix})$
```