# How to add normal brackets around a tabular environment or create similar effect?

Tags: tables, matrices, brackets

I want to mimmick this layout:

[image]

But I do not have access to the source code. My best guess is that this is a tabular environment with brackets typeset arround it.

Comment: You could give the pmatrix from the amsmath package a try. For other possibilities you might also have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28608/134144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the most direct way to typeset a 2-row matrix surrounded by parentheses is to use a `pmatrix` environment. It can also be done with an `array` environment, but it's a bit more work. I wouldn't a `tabular` environment, since the contents of the present array would appear to be math material, not text material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' and 'align*' environments
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sigma 
&= \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 
\end{pmatrix} \\
   %% '@{\mkern1mu}' reduces the amount of whitespace to left and right of array
&= \left( \begin{array}{@{\mkern1mu}cccc@{\mkern1mu}}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 
\end{array} \right) 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

One simple way could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ 
3 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 7
\end{pmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]