# How can I write this matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, symbols, matrices

I've tried the following in order to reproduce the screenshot below, but I haven't been successful. Any suggestions?

```
\begin{gather*}
    [p(\theta)]= \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
    {\left[
    \cos({\theta}) \cos (\theta -\frac{2\pi}{3}) \cos{\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}}  
    -\sin({\theta}) -\sin (\theta -\frac{2\pi}{3}) -\sin{\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}} 
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
    \right]}
\end{gather*}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that this is an English speaking site. If you prefer to ask your latex questions in French, have a look at https://texnique.fr/osqa/

Comment: What problem is preventing you from entering this equation on overleaf?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28608

Comment: I've taken the liberty of translating your posting from French to Engiish. Feel free to revert.

Comment: The delimiters appear to be verticals, not brackets.  The `amsmath` environment `vmatrix` would therefore be suitable.

Answer (score 7):

What you need is a `bmatrix` -- short for "**matrix** surrounded by square **b**rackets" -- environment. I suppose it's a matter of taste whether one prefers `\frac` notation or inline-fraction notation for the terms in the cells of the matrix.

Both possibilities are illustrated in the following screenshot. For the upper matrix -- the one that uses `\frac` notation -- I suggest (a) using `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` for the parentheses that enclose the `\frac{2\pi}{3}` terms and (b) increasing the spacing between the rows by `\jot` (a length parameter with a default value of `3pt`) in order to keep the cell contents from touching each other. Note that these adjustments aren't necessary in the lower matrix -- the one that employs inline-fraction notation. The lower matrix is wider than the upper matrix, but takes up less vertical space.

[image]

Note the use of `\phantom{-}` directives in row 1 of each matrix to align the cells' contents with those in row 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' env.

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
[P(\theta)]
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
   \begin{bmatrix}
          \phantom{-}\cos(\theta) 
       &  \phantom{-}\cos\bigl(\theta - \frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr) 
       &  \phantom{-}\cos\bigl(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr) \\[\jot] 
         -\sin(\theta) 
       & -\sin\bigl(\theta - \frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr) 
       & -\sin\bigl(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr)  \\[\jot]
          \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
       &  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
       &  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
   \end{bmatrix} \\[2\jot] % end of first row
&= \sqrt{2/3}
   \begin{bmatrix}
          \phantom{-}\cos(\theta) 
       &  \phantom{-}\cos(\theta - 2\pi/3) 
       &  \phantom{-}\cos(\theta + 2\pi/3) \\ 
         -\sin(\theta) 
       & -\sin(\theta - 2\pi/3) 
       & -\sin(\theta + 2\pi/3)  \\
          1/\sqrt{2} 
       &  1/\sqrt{2} 
       &  1/\sqrt{2}
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `tabularray` to enhence the `bmatrix`. In the second example, I add  a blank before first row to align with second row.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
[P(\theta)]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\begin{+bmatrix}
\cos({\theta})     & \cos (\theta -\frac{2\pi}{3})  & \cos(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3})  \\
-\sin({\theta})    & -\sin (\theta -\frac{2\pi}{3}) & -\sin(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}) \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}             & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}             \\
\end{+bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
[P(\theta)]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\begin{+bmatrix}[row{1}={preto=\hphantom{-}}]
\cos({\theta})     & \cos (\theta -\frac{2\pi}{3})  & \cos(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3})  \\
-\sin({\theta})    & -\sin (\theta -\frac{2\pi}{3}) & -\sin(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}) \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}             & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}             \\
\end{+bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can reproduce the picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\[
[P(\theta)]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \cos(\theta-\dfrac{2\pi}{3}) & \cos(\theta+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}) \\
-\sin\theta & -\sin(\theta-\dfrac{2\pi}{3}) & -\sin(\theta+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}) \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, looking at the output, you clearly see that there are several aspects to fix:

1. the parentheses are wrong, because too short;
2. the first two lines touch each other;
3. the symbols are too big inside the matrix.

You might fix just the first two aspects noted above. First of all with NewTX instead of `mathptmx`, larger parentheses and some vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[
[P(\theta)]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \cos\Bigl(\theta-\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr) & \cos\Bigl(\theta+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr)
\\[2ex]
-\sin\theta & -\sin\Bigl(\theta-\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr) & -\sin\Bigl(\theta+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr)
\\[1.5ex]
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd use smaller fractions in the first two rows and slashed fractions in the last row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[
[P(\theta)]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \cos\bigl(\theta-\frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr) & \cos\bigl(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr)
\\[1ex]
-\sin\theta & -\sin\bigl(\theta-\frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr) & -\sin\bigl(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}\bigr)
\\[1ex]
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Going with the OP's screenshot, what may be needed is not so much `\lvert P(\theta)\rvert` but, rather, `\begin{bmatrix} P(\theta) \end{bmatrix}`. +1, otherwise. (I employed the OP's own code, `[p(\theta)]`, in my answer, but I agree that `P` is more precise than `p`.)

Comment: @Mico Thanks: i need to check my glasses…