# Is there a shorthand for matrices that doesn't use an environment

Tags: environments, matrices

I understand that environments are very nice where the content is complex.  But for simple cases, the `\begin` and `\end` and duplication of the environment name gets quite wordy and dominates the actual content.

Is there a non-environment command to create a matrix, like exists for `\frac`?

Compare:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
      \chi_2 \\
      \chi_3
\end{bmatrix} = \chi_1 + \begin{bmatrix}
                             t_2 - t_1 & 0 \\
                             t_3 - t_1 & t_3 - t_2
                         \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
                                            \nu_1 \\
                                            \nu_2
                                       \end{bmatrix}
```

to a hypothetical

```
\bcolvec{\chi_2}{\chi_3}
       = \chi_1 + \inbmatrix{t_2 - t_1 & 0}{t_3 - t_2 & t_2 - t_1} \bcolvec{\nu_2}{\nu_3}
```

Comment: You can define it: `\newcommand*\bcolvec[2]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\\#2\end{matrix}}`.

Comment: @Manuel: Any way to have a variable number of rows? (whether auto-detected or I have to supply the row count as an argument)  If you can write a command to do that it would be an answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt if you want multiple rows just define `\newcommand*\bcolvec[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{matrix}}` and use `\bcolvec{a\\b\\c\\d}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- better make that `\end{bmatrix}` instead of just `matrix`.

Comment: There are a few questions and answers that deal with column vectors: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/typesetting-column-vector and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39051/typesetting-a-row-vector

Comment: thanks @egreg.  I think I may just go with the simple `\newcommand*\bmtx[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}`