# Automatically use \cr or & (for matrices) in macro?

Tags: macros, matrices, comma-separated-list, pgffor

I'm trying to write a macro to abstract different possible representations of matrices.  In particular, we're changing whether we want to represent a particular matrix as a column or row vector.  My hope was to do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,pgffor}


\newcommand\Hor[1]{\begin{pmatrix}\foreach \n [count=\ni] in {#1} {\ifnum \ni=1 \n \else &\n \fi}\end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand\Ver[1]{\begin{pmatrix}\foreach \n [count=\ni] in {#1} {\ifnum \ni=1 \n \else \cr\n \fi}\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Some things that work}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \cr 2 \cr 3
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\section*{Some things that don't}

\[
\Hor{1,2,3}
\]

\[
\Ver{1,2,3}
\]

\end{document}
```

In particular, I'd like to be able to have a single macro which switches between row and column matrices, ergo using `\foreach` instead of just having `&`s or `\cr`s in the arguments.

This seems like it should be easy... what am I missing?

Comment: The `\foreach` loop is grouped.

Comment: You might be interested in [Is there a way to automatically transpose a matrix written in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283081/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-transpose-a-matrix-written-in-latex) which shows many ways to create the transpose of  a matrix. The `sagetex` solution given there will be helpful if you're doing extensive work with matrices. For example, [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/special.html) or [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix0.html?highlight=transpose)

Comment: why `\cr`??? `\cr` is not supported syntax for any ams or standard latex matrix construct. It is a tex primitive that underlies `\\ `  so it sometimes works but it shouldn't be used in pmatrix ever.

Answer (score 5):

As Henri said in the comment, the `\foreach` loop is grouped, so it isn't really fit for this type of application. You can use `expl3`'s `\seq_use:Nn <seq var> {<thing>}` to add `<thing>` between each item of `<seq var>`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_trevion_tmp_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \Hor { m }
  { \trevion_pmatrix:nn {#1} { & } } % Use main command with arg and &
\NewDocumentCommand \Ver { m }
  { \trevion_pmatrix:nn {#1} { \\ } } % Use main command with arg and \\
\cs_new_protected:Npn \trevion_pmatrix:nn #1 #2
  {
    % Split the argument at each comma, and store in the seq var
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_trevion_tmp_seq {#1}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      % Use the seq var with #2 (& or \\) between each pair of items
      \seq_use:Nn \l_trevion_tmp_seq {#2}
    \end{pmatrix}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section*{Some things that work}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \cr 2 \cr 3
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\section*{Some things that don't}

\[
\Hor{1,2,3}
\]

\[
\Ver{1,2,3}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: :( too slow, just wanted to post almost the same.

Comment: @Skillmon Isn't there a story about a Tortoise and a Hare? ;-)

Comment: Well, of course mine is fundamentally different, I called the function `\trevion_horver:nn` and the order of arguments was flipped...

Comment: @Skillmon Well, that's the same as code I proposed in 2012: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39054/4427

Answer (score 4):

It's easier if you  use a command as separator, as then no loop is required.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,pgffor}


\newcommand\Hor[1]{{\def\,{&}\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}
\newcommand\Ver[1]{{\def\,{\\}\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\Hor{1\,2\,3}
\]

\[
\Ver{1\,2\,3}
\]

\end{document}
```