# How can I type an expression of a column vector

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to type a column vector like below:

```
     [  dx     ]
UI = [  dy     ]
     [  dtheta ]
```

`U` is the name of this vector, and `I` is the subscript. Two brackets like the matrix style.
`dx`, `dy` and `dtheta` are actually three items with a dot on their head, and theta is a Greek letter.

Comment: For `dx`, `dy` and `dtheta`, you could use `\dot{x}`, `\dot{y}` and `\dot{\theta}`.

Comment: If I also want a number of this equation like Ui= [x \\ y \\ theta] (4) (4) is behind the expression indicating its NO.
How can I do this? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Instead of `\[...\]` use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array to create a vector. See section 3 of the [Not so Short Guide to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english) for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{U}_I =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\mathrm{d}x \\
\mathrm{d}y \\
\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{array}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

The spacing around between the elements and the brackets can be reduced by replacing `{c}` with `{@{}c@{}}`. You could also consider using the `bmatrix` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Note that `\[` and `\]` create an equation that is not numbered. If you need a numbered equation you should use `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` instead.

Comment: If I also want a number of this equation like 
Ui= [x \\ y \\ theta]    (4) 

(4) is behind the expression indicating its NO.
How can I do this? 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Possibly `\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}`?

Comment: @user18441 --- I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
\( U_i = \left[ \dot{dx}, \dot{dy}, \dot{d \theta} \right] \)
```

Well, you can replace the `\[,\]` with any other brace of your taste, e.g. `\left(,\right)` or `\left\{,\right\}`. In addition, instead of `dx` you can have something like `\mathrm{d}x` to have something similar to derivative.

In addition, if you wish you wish to have column vector, refer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2705/412) and the answers following it.

### Edit:

If you want to have a numbered version of the expression, put the expression between the `\(`, and `\)`, that is what in the math-mode, inside an `equation` environment.

Comment: Probably `\left[` and `\right]`, not with the additional backslash; but `\left` and `\right` are redundant and possibly wrong.

Comment: @egreg my bad. I corrected the code

Comment: @Dror I would remove the `\left` and `\right`: it's a bad habit to always add them. In this particular case the output is worse than it would have been without them, just try and look closely at the spacing.

Comment: If I also want a number of this equation like Ui= [x \\ y \\ theta] (4) (4) is behind the expression indicating its NO. How can I do this? Thanks in advanced.