# Typesetting a Row Vector - Vol 2

Tags: vector

If one would just **read** the question, one could easily understand that this is not a duplicate.

Previously in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/typesetting-column-vector) question, it was asked how to typeset a column vector. Two answers were present,

- First one used such syntax: `\colvec{1}{2}{3}`
- and the second one was like this: `\colvec{1;2;3}`

Now I like the second one, because it seems shorter are more concise. Regarding this, another user had asked [how to typeset a row vector](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/typesetting-column-vector). The answer given to that question had a syntax similar to the first bullet. I would like some help converting the one **which uses semicolons** into a row vector function, (original is given below):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Spvek}[2][r]{%
  \gdef\@VORNE{1}
  \left(\hskip-\arraycolsep%
    \begin{array}{#1}\vekSp@lten{#2}\end{array}%
  \hskip-\arraycolsep\right)}

\def\vekSp@lten#1{\xvekSp@lten#1;vekL@stLine;}
\def\vekL@stLine{vekL@stLine}
\def\xvekSp@lten#1;{\def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\vekL@stLine
  \else
    \ifnum\@VORNE=1\gdef\@VORNE{0}
    \else\@arraycr\fi%
    #1%
    \expandafter\xvekSp@lten
  \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
\Spvek{1;-2} \quad \Spvek[l]{1;-2;3}\quad \Spvek[c]{1;-2;-3}\quad\Spvek{1;2;-3;4}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `\@arraycr` by `\hspace{\arraycolsep}`.

Comment: @Sigur - Something odd seems to be going on in the typesetting process after `\@arraycr` has been replaced with `\hspace{\arraycolsep}`: The unary `-` signs, which should be typeset flush against their associated numbers, are being typeset as binary `-` signs, i.e., with a noticeable (and typographically inappropriate) amount of whitespace inserted.

Comment: @Mico Yeah, it poses a problem. Replacing with ``\hskip\col@sep`` also works, but doesnt solve that problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @nrs: My suggestion -- see also my separate answer -- would be to encase the negative numbers in curly braces.

Comment: @nico hmm I tried putting #1 (at line 17) in curly braces and I think it worked. What do you think?

Comment: @Sigur Could you post your answer with ``\hskip\col@sep`` and the curly braces around ``#1`` so I can accept it? Maybe you could also mention the unary minus sign problem, and how it is solved by putting curly braces?

Comment: It does not work here with you command. I don't know why.

Comment: @Sigur, ok doesn't matter. You can also post the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. It could produce some strange errors on negative numbers, according to the comments along this post.

I'm just replacing `\@arraycr`  by `\hspace{\arraycolsep}`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Spvek}[2][r]{%
  \gdef\@VORNE{1}
  \left(\hskip-\arraycolsep%
    \begin{array}{#1}\vekSp@lten{#2}\end{array}%
  \hskip-\arraycolsep\right)}

\def\vekSp@lten#1{\xvekSp@lten#1;vekL@stLine;}
\def\vekL@stLine{vekL@stLine}
\def\xvekSp@lten#1;{\def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\vekL@stLine
  \else
    \ifnum\@VORNE=1\gdef\@VORNE{0}
    \else\hspace{\arraycolsep}\fi%   %% here is the setup
    {#1}%
    \expandafter\xvekSp@lten
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Some users had commented about a possible problem with negative sign which could be interpreted as binary operator instead of unary operator. But I can not see this happening on my sample.

[image]

Comment: Do you used the same macro for both examples, because they look somehow the same to me?

Comment: @nrs, yes, the same! I didn't have problem with minus sign.

Comment: ah, but the problem arises when there are no curly braces inside the macro definition around ``#1``. After adding curly braces around ``#1``, there is no need for additional braces when writing a vector.

Comment: could you please accept my edit?

Comment: Did you read the comments there?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see what's wrong with typing the row vectors directly, i.e., without first cloaking them in a new environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\?}{\mkern12mu} % extra-wide horizontal skip in mathmode
\begin{document}
$ \mathbf{x}_{1\times n} = (x_1\? x_2\? \dots\? x_n) $

$ (1\? {-2}\? {-3}\? 4) $
\end{document}
```

Note that if the row vector contains negative numbers, they should be encased in curly braces so that TeX won't mistakenly interpret the `-` symbols as binary operators. Clearly, the `-` symbols should be typeset as unary operators in this situation.

Comment: Fair enough, but I love it when I can type clearer and smaller code ^^. I am working on it